# How to make dirty or touched input programmatically in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I needs to use  one jquery plugin with Angular2.In General terms, this plugin creates a copy of a piece of html, which has inputs.When data changes, angular2 rerenders it with all the errors etc.But Jquery must pass data back to angular2 when something changes.I did it through the

`ControlGroup.controls['control_id'].updateValue(value,{emitEvent,emitModelToViewChange}).`

All is well,data comes.But angular2 input in which jquery passes  data doesn't become dirty or  touched, but I need it to display errors.How to force the input to be touched or dirty? Thanks in advance.

P.S: I know that all this is bad, but I have no choice

Answer (score 1):

There is a pull request to make these properties available https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7288/files

Currently it is marked
- touched when the input emits the `blur` event
- changed when the input emits the `input` event

These events probably vary between different types of input controls.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/default_value_accessor.ts

Comment: can I  get access to input from Control? to emit blur or input

Comment: As far as I know - no.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the `updateValueAndValidity` after calling the `updateValue` one:

```
var ctrl = ControlGroup.controls['control_id'];
ctrl.updateValue(value,{emitEvent,emitModelToViewChange});
ctrl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: doesnt work for me, still "ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"